# When executing pytest from the root of the project, ModuleNotFoundError: No module name 'main'

Tags: python, module, pytest, backend, fastapi

**PROBLEM**: When I execute pytest from the root of the project in the cmd `py -m pytest py_src/`. I get the following error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'main'`. However if I cd into py_src/ and then run `py -m pytest` everything behaves accordingly. I am still relatively new with pytest, anything would be appreciated to direct me in the right direction.

**GOAL**: What I am trying to achieve is to create a .yml file from the root of the project that will run the pytest and other tests in other directories.

**CURRENT STATE**: here is what my file structure looks like.

```
root
|
|---py_src
|    |
|    |---main.py
|    |
|    |---tests
|    |    |
|    |    |---test_x.py
```

in my tests.py file, I have

```
from main import app
```

Comment: can you post the directory structure for your app or main file?

Comment: you are right! I added it!

Answer (score 0):

make the directories modules by adding a blank file by the name `__init__.py` in each directory.

```
root
|
|---py_src
|    |
|    |---__init__.py
|    |---main.py
|    |
|    |---tests
|    |    |
|    |    |---__init__.py
|    |    |---test_x.py
```

Now change your import in `test_x.py` to import from module like

`from py_src.main import app`

This will allow you to run the pytest from either root or from the source directory